# Exclude page from ssl redirect rule

Tags: url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have a rewrite rule in my web.config that forces all pages to go to https.
Is there any way to exclude a single page.

So for example is didn't want http://www.example.com/thispage.ashx to redirect to https how could I modify the rule to exclude it?

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions><add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
 </conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an additional condition that matches all URLs except `/thispage.ashx`.

```xml
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/thispage\.ashx$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Notice: To test your new rule, make sure that you have cleared the browser's cache for the web site you're working on. Otherwise, you may fail to test whether the rule is working because of the client-side cached redirect responses.